# How do I specify collation when creating a table from select in mysql?

Tags: mysql, collation

When creating a table with **dynamically created and defined columns** from a select result, how can I specify collation as you do when creating a table with column definitions?

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ....
  ) )
```

The above creates the table with the dynamic columns just fine but it is not using the collation I want. It is using utf8_general_ci and I want it to be utf8_unicode_ci.

This below doesn't work

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ....
  ) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

it gives error message indicating the commands are not valid at this position.

I realize the above suggestion is not valid, so what method for achieving this is? I've tried setting the database collation thinking this was setting a default for the database for all tables created but it doesn't appear to behave like that - or 
 maybe I am not actually setting the default for the database when I `ALTER` the database collation. Is there a way to set a default for tables so they the first code block above creates the table using the desired collation?

The `SELECT...` results in the above code blocks refers to a variety of conditional/logical value setting using `case/when` statements, string parsing,  and function results - it is not just selecting columns one-to-one from another table that has defined columns so it is not as simple as defining the other table's columns.

I have already tried setting the database collation ahead of time using `ALTER DATABASE my_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` but this doesn't change the results. The tables are still created (and the columns in the tables) using `utf8_general_ci` when creating a table from a select (dynamically defined columns from select results)

Comment: The documentation on [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) outlines a few ways to do this sort of thing, but none of them match your expectations in the second case.

Comment: Right, which is why I am asking the question here(?) I provided the second code block above just as a suggestion of what I would like to work but I realize that it is not correct. I am looking for what the correct solution would be. The documentation refers to both the fact that you can create a table from a select and that table options for collation exist, but I can't find examples that show both of these two together. The `SELECT ....` from above is a collection of results created the various logic like `case when` expressions, other tables, and results of functions.

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    ... none, some, or all columns ...
) ... none, some, or all specifications ...  -- Here
    SELECT ...;
```

If that fails, then

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ( all columns ) all specs;
INSERT INTO my_table
    SELECT ...;
```

Or...

```
CREATE ... SELECT ...;
ALTER TABLE my_table ...;  -- any fixes needed
```

Yet another approach is to make sure that the `DATABASE` has the `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` and/or `DEFAULT COLLATION` desired before the `CREATE TABLE ...`.

Whatever you do, follow it with

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;
```

to verify that each column has desired `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION`.  If missing from the *column*, then look at the table's `DEFAULTs`.

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE `us` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `country` char(2) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'ISO 3166 Country Code',
  `ascii_city` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of city or town in ASCII encoding',
  `city` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'For US, ISO-3166-2 code for the state/province name.',
  `population` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lat` float NOT NULL,
  `lng` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `state` (`state`,`city`),
  KEY `state_2` (`state`,`population`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Notice the explicit `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE` on some columns, thereby overriding the `DEFAULT CHARSET` of the table.

When there is no collation, `CHARSET utf8` defaults to `COLLATE utf8_general_ci`.

**Example 2**

In this, I will create a new table `us2` from that table, but change the collation of `city`:

```
CREATE TABLE us2 (
  `city` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
)
    SELECT * from us;
```

Everything about `us2` will be the same as for `us` except for the collation of that one column.

Comment: When you say make sure the database *default* character set/collation is as desired, is this the same checking the variable? i.e. if I check the system variable `collation_database` in mysql client while using the database in question, it tells me `utf8_unicode_ci` however when the table is created as in the first example in my post, it gets created as `utf8_general_ci`. Is there some other method to checking/setting the *default* for the database other than `ALTER DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET charset COLLATE collation;` Is the database's options vs the default options for the db different?

Comment: To follow my last comment, I did try adding the word `DEFAULT` when using the alter database command:  `ALTER DATABASE my_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` and it still does not change the results I see. I still get tables that are created from a select using `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: To check the database's defaults, use `SHOW CREATE DATABASE dbname;`

Comment: Specifying `CHARACTER SET utf8` without specifying a collation gives you the default `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: The word `DEFAULT` is implied in that context.

Comment: When I check the database default's it shows `utf8_unicode_ci `. I can't seem to find where/at what level a specific collation is able to be set that is not set specifically to `utf8_unicode_ci`. And as far s the first part of your answer, this is for a dynamic setup in an application that runs the query so where you refer to column specifications, that is the part where I refer to it being dynamic or not known. I wrap a query coming from various configurations with a wildcard column select as part of the table create.

Comment: added an example.

Comment: Thanks but your example is showing how to create a table while also defining the columns. I am familiar with how to define the collation for a table and columns in that manner. The scenario I have is creating a table while letting the results of a select dynamically define the columns of the new table, which is why its not clear to me how to force the collation of that new table.

Comment: Put whatever you need to in the `CREATE` part; let the `SELECT` do the rest.  See "Example 2".

Answer (score 7):

The following did work for me on MariaDB version 10:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
SELECT *
FROM other_table
;
```